# Is it possible to set up an anti-spam system?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

So, I'm intending to create an anti-spam system where if a user sends 5 messages consecutively with a tiny amount of delay in between, I want it to automatically mute them for 1 minute and display an embed and have a time remaining field that edits itself with the seconds remaining until mute expiry.

How could I accomplish this?

Thanks.

*Note: I already have a role set up for muted users called "Muted".*

Comment: are you using socket.io or express?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using this:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-anti-spam

```
var anti_spam = require("discord-anti-spam");
antispam(bot,
{
    warnBuffer: 3, //Maximum amount of messages allowed to send in the interval time before getting warned.
    maxBuffer: 5, // Maximum amount of messages allowed to send in the interval time before getting banned.
    interval: 1000, // Amount of time in ms users can send a maximum of the maxBuffer variable before getting banned.
    warningMessage: "stop spamming or I'll whack your head off.", // Warning message send to the user indicating they are going to fast.
    banMessage: "has been banned for spamming, anyone else?", // Ban message, always tags the banned user in front of it.
    maxDuplicatesWarning = 7; // Maximum amount of duplicate messages a user can send in a timespan before getting warned
    maxDuplicatesBan = 10; // Maximum amount of duplicate messages a user can send in a timespan before getting banned
});
```

Comment: This is a bad module to use; its poorly coded and doesn't execute as required properly.